# How to sort array of list of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array which has list of objects.
[image]

each value of array looks like :
[image]

I want to sort name :  `elements[ele].options.name`.

this is what I am trying to do ,but not working for me

```
           var sortedElements = elements.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.options.name - b.options.name
            });
            for (var ele in sortedElements) {
                if (sortedElements.hasOwnProperty(ele)) {
                    if (!sortedElements[ele].options.outOfNetworkFlag) {
                        if (sortedElements[ele].options.category === "person") {
                            assignCount++
                        }
                        if (sortedElements[ele].options.category === "unknown") {
                            unassignCount++
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        oonCount++;
                    }

                    occupancylist += '<a href="#" class="elementLink"><li style="list-style: none" data-elementid="' + sortedElements[ele].options.elementId + '">' + sortedElements[ele].options.icon.options.html + ' ' + sortedElements[ele].options.name + '</li></a>';
                }
            }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You can't subtract a string from another string. To compare strings, use `.localeCompare()`: `return a.options.name.localeCompare(b.options.name);`

Comment: Thank you Pointy, this is working 100%

Comment: @Pointy Yes you can in most cases sort on ascii. You need localeCompare if there are chars other than `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: @mplungjan OK yes, I agree that that's often fine, but it remains true that the comparison needs to account for equal sort keys.

Comment: @mplungjan indeed, in my personal experience I don't have to deal with anything other than Latin 1, but `.localeCompare()` is just convenient and I'm pretty sure it won't do anything that seems wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method

```
  var items = [
      { name: 'saurabh'},
      { name: 'hello'},
      { name: 'jsbee'},
      { name: 'abc'}
    ];

    // sort by name
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
      var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
      var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      }

      // names must be equal
      return 0;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just use [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let src = [{options: {name: 'bbb'}}, {options: {name: 'aaa'}}]
 
src.sort((a, b) => a.options.name > b.options.name ? 1 : -1)

console.log(src);
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. The sort comparator has to return a **number**, not a boolean.

Comment: Besides fixing the answer so it isn't wrong, this answer also needs an explanation.

Comment: @Pointy sorting using ascii order does actually work

Comment: Guys please stop downvoting, fixed it already

Comment: @mplungjan please be cautious with editing: in your (first) edit you destroyed an improvement from the author.

Comment: @mplungjan no it does not, not with a simple `>` comparison in general. It might work for some particular lists, but it simply cannot work in all cases.

Comment: I agree with Pointy: don't destroy the author's improvement.

Comment: If the comparator does not return 0 for equal strings, it will confuse the sort algorithm.

Comment: Not returning 0 is ok, because equal strings would be next to each other which is ok I guess

Comment: And thanks to those who defended my improvements :-)

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I did not willingly DESTROY anything. We were just editing at the same time. Please add the SNIPPET I made for you and do with it what you want

Comment: Sir, just let's go to some next question leaving this one as it is

Comment: You can add snippet if you want *now*, no one is against it :-) it's just that your first two editions overwrote my ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort` function like this:

```
objs.sort((a,b) => (a.options.name > b.options.name) ? 1 : ((b.options.name > a.options.name) ? -1 : 0));
```

Of course you can use `toUpperCase()` (or lower) in sort function.

```
objs.sort((a,b) => (a.options.name.toUpperCase() > b.options.name.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : ((b.options.name.toUpperCase() > a.options.name.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : 0));
```